# Best way of displaying form validation errors in a Node.js app using Express?

Tags: node.js, express

Our registration and login forms require server-side validation logic. I'd like to come up with the best way of displaying messages for each input block on the client.

The application flow:

1. Client side form submit
2. Validation on node
3. Redirect to the view that rendered the form in step 1.

I'm leaning toward `req.flash()` to display form input messages but perhaps there is a more OOP approach to this?

Comment: This problem has inspired me to write a node module with a client side script for AJAX validation. The idea is to setup the form fields in a similar way to mongoose Schema, i.e with validation rules, on the server. Client side code will be dynamically generated and take care of jQuery change listeners and form submission to validate before a submit. The form is then accessed in the usual way via `req.body` (if using body parser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a validation middleware that will validate form data. I can tell the middleware what form to rerender if validation fails and it will have an errors object with the name of the field and an array of errors that field has.

My forms end up looking like this:

```
include ../mixins/form-helpers

mixin errors()

form(action=url('messages_create'), method='post')

  mixin csrf()

  fieldset

    legend contact

    mixin field('text', 'subject', 'Subject')
    mixin field('textarea', 'message', 'Message')

  .form-actions
    mixin submit('Send')
```

If I post this form without subject and message I set the following object.

```
var errors = { subject: ['is required'], message: ['is required'] };
```

My errors mixin will render all the errors and my field mixin will add an error class so I can add a red border to my failing fields.

Comment: Any repo you could share so we could see the whole thing from beginning to end?

Comment: The module I use to validate is on github: https://github.com/Enome/square/tree/master/validation It's mostly for personal use so the docs are kinda shitty. My mixin file looks something like: https://gist.github.com/2727378

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Validity](https://github.com/afincha/validity). It is designed specifically for attaching validations and errors to form input fields and rendering them appropriately.